# How can I make QMainWindow refresh when QWidget is closed?[PyQt5]

Tags: python, class, oop, pyqt, pyqt5

I am currently making an application with PyQt5 and I am trying to find a way to refresh the main window when the QWidget it calls is closed. 
My main window page looks like this:

```
import sys
import glob
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from addClass import addClass

class TeacherMain(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        x = 30
        y = 80

        buttonContainer = QLabel(self)
        buttonContainer.setStyleSheet("background-color: #5D4A41;")
        buttonContainer.move(20, 70)
        buttonContainer.resize(1240, 550)
        buttonContainer.show()

        classes = glob.glob("Folder/*.csv") 
        classes = [j.strip("Folder/") for j in [i.strip('.csv') for i in classes]]
        for k in classes: 
            classButton = QPushButton(k, self)
            classButton.move(x, y)
            classButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
            classButton.resize(143, 143)
            classButton.clicked.connect(self.viewClass)
            x += 153 ## Increase value of x.
            if x >= 1235:
                y += 153
                x = 30

        addClass = QPushButton("Add Class...", self)
        addClass.move(x, y)
        addClass.resize(143, 143)
        addClass.clicked.connect(self.createClass)

        quit = QPushButton("Quit", self)
        quit.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        quit.move(630, 645)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #AD9A90;")
        self.setWindowTitle("SheikhCoin Teacher")
        self.setFixedSize(1280, 690)
        self.show()

    def createClass(self):
        self.new_window = addClass()
        self.new_window.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = TeacherMain()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And my QWidget looks like this:

```
class addClass(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self, granted):
        className = QLabel("Class Name", self)
        className.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt Comic Sans MS")

        self.nameBox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.nameBox.resize(200, 20)
        self.nameBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")

        add = QPushButton("Add Class", self)
        add.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        add.clicked.connect()

    def create(self):
        name = self.nameBox.text()
        path = "Folder/" + name + ".csv"
        classRows = [["Student Key", "Prefix", "Forename", "Surname", "Tutor"]]
        with open(path, 'w') as file:
            write = csv.writer(newClass, delimiter=',')
            write.writerows(classRows)
        self.close()
```

Once the file is created in the QWidget, I would like the Main Window to update to show the file that has just been added as a button, as is done with the files already in `Folder` when the Main Window is first opened.

Anybody have any idea how to do this?

Comment: what is granted??

Comment: What new buttons should be added? And where?

Comment: granted is a list variable that has been passed from the previous window. Also I have updated the code to show how new buttons will be added through the use of a for loop that checks the contents of a specified folder in the directory and creates a button for each file within it.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], that is, a code that I can copy, paste and execute.

Comment: Hey, I’ve made the changes and now the code is executable.